# Why Random Forest Generate Different Outputs from the same input

Tags: output, random-forest

I use `RandomForestRegressor` in my project. After training step and saving the model, I am reading this model in my run. (i.e., training step is not repeated.) 
Why Random Forest Generate Different Outputs with the same input in different Runs?

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
# Generate Data
# Loading Trained Model

predictions = rf.predict(test[Effective_Columns])
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information, including what RandomForest is supposed to do and what programming language you're using.

It's generally desirable for a random generator to have different output on successive runs - you need to modify the seed to be constant to get the same output for different inputs.

Comment: I assume that you use python but please state the programming language. About the random forest, how many trees etc is the default?